# TypeScript: Error TS2345 to return Promise.all() in a Dialog

Tags: typescript, promise, dialog

I have the following function in TypeScript:

```
    private async deleteSelectedLuminaires (): Promise<any[]> {
    return this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: DeleteLuminaire, model: 'Cancel or Ok', lock: false })
    .whenClosed((response) => {
      if (!response.wasCancelled) {
        const requests = this.selectedSerials
          .map(async (serial) => this.luminaireApi.removeLuminaire({ serial }))

        return Promise.all(requests)
      }
    })
  }
```

this.luminaireApi.removeLuminaire function returns Promise< void >.
In this function, I ask a question via Dialog service to delete some items. 
When I delete the dialog, everything is ok, but the above code gives me back the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(response: DialogCloseResult) =>
>   Promise | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '(value: DialogCloseResult) => any[] | PromiseLike'.   Type
>   'Promise | undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[] |
>   PromiseLike'.
>       Type 'undefined' is not
>   assignable to type 'any[] | PromiseLike'.

I am sure the problem is using dialog and Promise.all together, but I don't know why.
Could you please help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, as you see here:

```
private async deleteSelectedLuminaires (): Promise<any> {
    let promises: Promise<any>

    return this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: DeleteEntries, model: 'Cancel or Ok', lock: false })
      .whenClosed(async (response) => {
        if (!response.wasCancelled) {
          promises = Promise.all(this.selectedSerials
            .map(async (serial) => this.luminaireApi.removeLuminaire({ serial })))
        }

        return promises
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a method that returns *either* a `Promise` or `undefined` (i.e. you are missing a return statement in a code branch).

That's what `(response: DialogCloseResult) => Promise | undefined` refers to.

The solution to your problem would be to ensure that your method handling a DialogCloseResult returns only a Promise, and not undefined. If you aren't in control of that signature, you may need a type guard, or type assertion on that return value.

Type Guard

```
if (typeof returnValue !== 'undefined') {
    // Then it is a promise here

}
```

Type Assertion

```
promiseValue = <Promise>returnValue;
```